# error undefined reference when a library is included to arduino code from directory other than src in sketch folder

Tags: c++, arduino

code.ino:

```
 #include "./(src or comp)/lib/one.h"
```

---

Case 1:

```
sketchfolder/code.ino
sketchfolder/src/lib/one.h
sketchfolder/src/lib/one.cpp
```

Now when code.ino is compiled  in arduino IDE everything works fine.

---

Case 2:

```
sketchfolder/code.ino
sketchfolder/comp/lib/one.h
sketchfolder/comp/lib/one.cpp
```

Now when code.ino is compiled in arduino IDE it throws an error.

error:

```
sketch/code.ino.cpp.o:(.literal.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_sens+0x8): undefined reference to `one::one()'
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino IDE will only compile source files in the `src` directory and subdirectories (see [this pull request](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/pull/148))